# Android method not being called

Tags: android

**In my fragment's onCreateView i run this method**

> ```
>     List<Product> mProducts = Database.getDatabase(mRef).getProducts();
> ```

**Here is my Database Class :**

```
public class Database {
    private FirebaseDatabase mDb;
    private DatabaseReference dbRef;
    private static Database sDatabase;
    private List<Product> mProducts;

    public static Database getDatabase(DatabaseReference ref) {
        if(sDatabase == null) {
            sDatabase = new Database(ref);
        }
        return sDatabase;
    }

    public Database(DatabaseReference mReference) {
        this.mDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        this.dbRef = mReference;
    }




    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mProducts.add(data.getValue(Product.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return mProducts;
    }
```

While going trough debugger, getProducts() method isn't being called, it goes and creates a new instance of Database and never reaches getProducts() method. The List later on is used for recyclerView adapter.

Answer (score 0):

**mProducts** will be empty list because addValueEventListener take some time to come back and u are returning value just after setting the listener
Solution is you have to send back some callback when you get list of product in callback method **onDataChange**

Comment: thanks i understood what you mean but i dont know how till that look in code.

Comment: pass some reference of some interface which implementation in the class from which you are calling getProducts. Then update data in the list from callback method of interface.